# Como detengo una clase que hereda de AsyncTask en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Hola estoy programando un boton en Android Studio y quiero que me mande un mensaje despues de que el boton este presionado durante 2 segundos, pero cuando mi contador llega a 2 y quiero mostrar un Toast me detiene la aplicación.
Creo una variable booleana para saber si esta presionado o no el botón y un contador para saber cuantos segundos lleva presionado:

```
boolean estaPresionado = false;
int contador = 0;
```

Aquí le asigno un evento a mi botón:

```
btnAlerta1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Mensaje no enviado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            btnAlerta1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                            if (!estaPresionado) {
                                estaPresionado = true;
                                new EnviarContadorTarea().execute();
                            }
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            estaPresionado = false;

                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Mando a llamar creando una instancia de la clase EnviarContadorTarea que es la siguiente:

```
private class EnviarContadorTarea extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        while(estaPresionado) {
            int con = AumentarContador();
            if (con == 2){
                mostrarMensaje();
                contador = 0;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Ahí mando a llamar el metodo que se repite para aumentar el contador:

```
private int AumentarContador(){

        contador = contador+1;
        Log.i("Contador","contador: "+contador);

        return contador;
    }
```

Y por ultimo cuando el contador llega a 2 mando a llamar el metodo mostrarMensaje:

```
private void mostrarMensaje() {

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Mensaje enviado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Pero cuando presiono el boton y llega a 2 se detiene inesperadamente y me manda este error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:209)
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:123)
    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:350)
    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:106)
    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:264)
```

Comment: Tienes que utilizaar esto y ya lo tinenes arreglado (si no surge otra cosa): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper

Comment: Gracias voy a revisarlo ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tema es que estás tratando de mandar un Toast a la pantalla en un Thread que no es el thread de UI (interfaz de usuario). Cualquer actualización a la interface de usuario se tiene que hacer en ese thread.

Esto se puede hacer con `Activity#runOnUiThread`, pero como estás usando AsyncTask también lo podes hacer directamente con métodos de esa clase.

Con AsyncTask podes usar `publishProgress()`, y `onProgressUpdate()`, que corren en UI thread.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    boolean terminar = false;
    while(estaPresionado && !terminar) {
        int con = AumentarContador();
        if (con == 2){
            publishProgress();
            terminar = true;
            contador = 0;
            continue;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress){
      mostrarMensaje();  
}
```

Nota: Tené en cuenta que el tipo de dato de del progress lo define el tipo del medio en la definición del AsyncTask: `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`

Comment: Si funciona, pero si sigo presionando el botón la tarea se vuelve a ejecutar no hay manera de detener una vez que el Toast es mostrado y que se ejecute, pero ya la siguiente vez que se presiona el botón?

Comment: Ahi le agregué un flag para que termine después de publicar el mensaje y el continue es para que no espere un segundo más antes de terminar.

Comment: Gracias bro de verdad lo implementare ;)